# Element.Type 'Class' vs 'Table' using Database Builder

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm working with some database models in EA Sparx, and when I click on a table sometimes it shows up in EA Sparx Enterprise Architect 12 as

```
Type='Class', Stereotype='table'
```

and other times as

```
Type='Table', Stereotype='table'
```

If I try to change the Element Type, the ones marked Class are changeable but the ones marked Table (notice Table never appears in the element types) are not changeable.

When I query the database behind the scenes I see that

```
object.Object_Type = 'Class'
```

Why does the user interface have this inconsistency?  I can't for the life of me see why they are different and where this difference is recorded in the EA repository.

Thank you,
Juraj

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  t_object.Object_id,
  t_xref.Description
from
  t_object inner join 
  t_xref on t_object.ea_guid = t_xref.Client
where
  t_object.Object_Type = 'Class'
  and t_object.Stereotype = 'table'
;
```

There's a lot of magic going on here.

There were two different kinds of values being captured, some are Fully-Qualified-Name of EAUI::table while others are EAUML::table.  (Probably depends on which tool you reverse engineer from.)

```
@STEREO;Name=table;GUID={57EF048F-695B-467b-8120-15C6CB6DA398};FQName=EAUI::table;@ENDSTEREO;
@STEREO;Name=table;FQName=EAUML::table;@ENDSTEREO;
```

The shorter string, with `EAUML` is the Table/table and the other is the Class/table.

Comment: EA is well known for being inconsistent. The EAUML profile has been introduced in a later release, though it's a while ago. Your observation might be heritage.

Comment: How dangerous is it to change the t_xref.Description from one "flavour" to another?  I replaced the EAUI::table string (in its entirety) with the second, simpler one that says EAUML::table.   It seemed happy with it. ... but DB Compares started hanging indefinitely.  Did I miss something?  Thank you.

Comment: I think that should be fine. What do you mean by "DB Compares" ?

Comment: Tools  | Database Builder | right click model | Show Differences

Comment: If you open a new question with the details I might have a look.

Comment: Thank you.  If I can get a simple, reproducible problem, I will repost.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion comes like this:

- EA has a toolbox with an element Table. If you create that, it will produce an `EAUML::table` stereotype.
- Further you can create a simple class and enter `table` in the stereotype. This will render the same as the above. But now you have a stereotype `EAUI::table`

[image]

The left has been created with the toolbox. The right with manual stereotyping.

Funny I coined the acronym EAUI after Paolo's EA Unique Interface. Now this has a new facet.

Comment: You might report this as bug, but I guess it will not be fixed due to "compatibility reasons".